# Rigour papers on the topic of benchmarking classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, references

Being motivated by the paper [On Comparing Classifiers: Pitfalls to Avoid and a Recommended Approach](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1009752403260), I would like to ask for any rigour papers on the topic of benchmarking classifiers?

Comment: Someone has voted to close your question as too broad. Could you please try to edit your question and make it more specific what exactly about benchmarking interests you? There is hundreds or thousands of such papers and many different things can be compared (speed, performance etc.).